# CSS: grouping properties

Tags: css, syntax, properties

```
.myclass {
    border-top: solid 1px gray;
    border-bottom: solid 1px gray;
    background: #F2F2F2;
}
```

Is it possible to group properties that share a common definition, such as `border-top` and `border-bottom` in the example above.

Something like:

```
.myclass {
    border-top , border-bottom: solid 1px gray; /* <-- grouped properties */
    background: #F2F2F2;
}
```

TIA,

Answer (score 1):

You can using LESS or SASS (I believe), but if you don't want to use those, you can instead group selectors that will have the same property:

```
.myclass,
.myOtherClass,
.myAnotherClass,
#anIdForGoodMeasure
 {
    border-top: solid 1px gray;
    border-bottom: solid 1px gray;
    background: #F2F2F2;
}
```

This will apply the style to all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunaly border doesnt have a shorthand version (Like say margin/padding for example), it has to be the same for all, or different.

However what you can do - is say you want to style one side uniquely, is specify all of the box, then **underneath it**, override it with an individual style. Heres a little fiddle of what I mean.

http://jsfiddle.net/XxWwn/

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you're trying to do here,

This is the only border shorthand I know, without using SASS/LESS.

```
.myclass {
    border-color: red blue green coral;
    border-width: 1px 2px 3px 4px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

This the same shorthand as margins and padding (TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM, LEFT)